# Can we perform a cross-region restore for a MongoDB Atlas cluster snapshot?

Tags: mongodb, backup, restore

Our MongoDB Atlas cluster is present in AWS **us-east-1** region. Currently we are backing up the snapshots also to us-east-1 region. However, as part of our disaster recovery plan, we want to back up to **us-west-2** region, too, so that we can restore the cluster in us-west-2 region incase us-east-1 region goes down for some reason.

Now, the question we have is that, is it sufficient if we just backup to us-west-2 region and leave out the us-east-1 region backup so that we don't incur double costs on backup? Can we restore the snapshot we have in us-west-2 to us-east-1 also incase we want to?

I went through the documentation of MongoDB but couldn't find anything explicitly mentioned about this. Any help would be appreciated.